# Typeorm bulk update - update only if exist in the body

Tags: mysql, typescript, backend, typeorm

**Assumptions**

- There are multiple instances of one entity called `Product`.
- `Product` has three properties called 1) `id`, 2) `name`, and 3) `active`.
- Current instances in the database look like this:

  [
  {
  id:1,
  name:'A',
  active: 0
  },
  {
  id:2,
  name:'B',
  active: 1
  },
  {
  id:3,
  name:'C',
  active: 0
  },
  ]

**Problem**

I would like to update only some properties of multiple instances by their ids with query like this:

```
Product.update(
  [1,2] , // ids
  {
    name: 'example'
  }
)
```

What I expect is something like this:

```
[
  {
    id:1,
    name:'example',
    active: 0
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name:'example',
    active: 1
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name:'C',
    active: 0
  },
]
```

But this query set the rest of properties which is `active` in this example to default! The result is like this:

```
[
  {
    id:1,
    name:'example',
    active: 0
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name:'example',
    active: 0 // which is wrong!
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name:'C',
    active: 0
  },
]
```

**Questions**

1. How is it possible to only update existed properties in the query
   (e.g., `name`)?
2. How to solve this problem with using `save` method? (I can't pass `ids` to `save` method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with using `createQueryBuilder` :

```
await getManager()
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .update(Product)
  .set({
    name: 'example'
  })
  .where('id IN (:ids)', { ids: [1,2] })
  .execute();
```